# Android - How to get the image using Intent data

Tags: android, android-camera

I implemented the application for getting image from the camera album in sdcard.But it is not working properly.

Here **Intent** returns like this  Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content://media/external/images/media/9 typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }

In the code

**Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");**
Here **(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")**
this part returns **null**.

How to get the bitmap here please can anybody help me.

Code:

```
cam_images_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent cam_ImagesIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             cam_ImagesIntent.setType("image/*");
             startActivityForResult(cam_ImagesIntent, CAMERA_IMAGES_REQUEST); 
        }       
    }); 

    if(requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGES_REQUEST && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        System.out.println("data(CAMERA_IMAGES_REQUEST):"+data);
        if(data != null)
        {           
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            System.out.println("Bitmap(CAMERA_IMAGES_REQUEST):"+thumbnail);
            System.out.println("cap_image(CAMERA_IMAGES_REQUEST):"+cap_image);
            cap_image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail); 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("SDCard have no images");
            Toast.makeText(camera.this, "SDCard have no images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);        
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: The image URI is returned instead of Image itself. [Have a look here how to parse URI and get Image](https://web.archive.org/web/20120323110453/http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-file-path-of-gallery-image)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the following in your code:

```
 if(data != null)
    {           
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        filestring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

      Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filestring, options2);

        System.out.println("Bitmap(CAMERA_IMAGES_REQUEST):"+thumbnail);
        System.out.println("cap_image(CAMERA_IMAGES_REQUEST):"+cap_image);
        cap_image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail); 
    }
```

This should work.

Edit:
Also if you want a "thumbnail" do the following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(), selectedImageUriId,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                    (BitmapFactory.Options) null);
```

Comment: Here what is option2? can i replace this with null

Comment: options is to get the image parameters as to how you want to set it. Create it with BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

Comment: what is selectedImageUriId? Previous code is still not working  it returns the null for bitmap

Comment: you will have to get the numeric "ID" of the image path say "fileString". This means if the path is "some/somthing/4" then 4 is the ID of that image. This original ID should be passed on to getThumbnail().

Comment: For bitmap you should use BitmapFactory. Like this: BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathString, options);

Comment: Naresh, just do string operation on that file path string that you got. and get the id.

Comment: now i am adding your code but still is not working. it returns null only

Comment: Your Edited thumbnail code is working thanks for giving the valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Well the way go about doing this is very easy, just:

```
        //Get incoming intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null){
            handleIncomingData(intent);
        }


    public void handleIncomingData(Intent data){
        Uri imageSelected = data.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageSelected);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Remember to put this code after everything is initialized first or else you will get a `NullPointerException`. I prefer to put it at the bottom of the `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by writing fewer lines of codes.

```
 if(requestCode== your_request_code){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri = data.getData();  //<----get the image uri
                imageView.setImageURI(uri); //<----set the image uri
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this code:

```
public void onGalleryRequest() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.selectImage)),
            GALLERY_REQ);
}
```

and then in onActivityResult I make this test:

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && data != null
            && resultCode != 0)
```

it works for me api level 7

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive image from Sharing File, here the code (Kotlin)

```html
if (intent.type?.startsWith("image/") == true) {
            (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri)?.let {

            }
        }
}
```